# Как сделать var DateTime глобальной переменной

Tags: c#

Как сделать `var newTime` глобальной переменной? Надо прибавить 30 минут и в условии сравнить с текущим временем

```
if (timerCheck == 0)
{

    var today = DateTime.Now;

    var interval = new TimeSpan(00, 30, 00);

    var newTime = today + interval;

    timerCheck = 1;
}
if (timerCheck == 1) 
{
    var today = DateTime.Now;

    if (today >= newTime) 
    {
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Т.е. глобальной? Нужна видимость в блоке второго if'а? Или еще откуда-то?

Comment: @KirillZharov ну так почему бы в начале класса не объявить эту переменную а ля `DateTime time = new  DateTime()` ?

Comment: И этот фрагмент используется внутри метода, который вызывается для проверки, так?
Почему не сделали тогда, как timerCheck, которое наверно является полем

Comment: Вроде никак, попробуйте по-другому

Comment: а давайте напишем в тегах что же мы все-таки используем... а то как-то c# слишком туманно.

Comment: кстати, ни один из трех ответов так и не дал ответа на вопрос, ждем топикстартера...

Answer (score 1):

```
var newTime = DateTime.MinValue;

if (timerCheck == 0)
{
    newTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
    timerCheck = 1;
}

if (timerCheck == 1) 
{
    var today = DateTime.Now;

    if (today >= newTime) 
    {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Теряется смысл этих if'ов.

Comment: @nuts119 а это уже к автору вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать статик класс с чем нибудь таким

```
public static class GridStateNames
{
    public static DateTime CurrentDateTime { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
}
```

а можно сделать это через абстракцию. Хороший пример описывается в книге [Внедрение зависимостей в .NET](http://smarly.net/dependency-injection-in-net/di-catalog/di-patterns/ambient-context#text-22950). В этом случае вы можете спокойно писать юнит тесты.

Comment: Зачем эта обвертка? Одно и тоже будет при DateTime.Now.
Автор спрашивал про newTime.

Comment: ок))  public static DateTime CurrentDateTime { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Наверно данный фрагмент кода используется внутри метода, который вызывается для проверки.
Непонятно, что мешает завести поле для класса. Примерно так:

```
class Foo{
    private DateTime newTime;

    public void Check(int timeCheck) {
        var today = DateTime.Now;
        if (timerCheck == 0)
        {
            newTime = today + new TimeSpan(00, 30, 00);
            timerCheck = 1;
        }
        if (timerCheck == 1) 
        {
            if (today >= newTime) 
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если же имелось ввиду статические локальные переменные, как в C++, то в C# таких нет.